# Meaning of "triumph all the sweeter"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does "triumph all the sweeter" mean from this  [article](http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21697225-hillary-clinton-has-democratic-nomination-within-her-grasp-she-needs-bolder-ideas-what):

> Sometimes relief makes triumph all the sweeter.

Comment: The way to parse this sentence is "relief / makes / triumph / all the sweeter."  *All the Xer* is an idiomatic phrase that means, roughly, "even more X than expected".  See http://www.yourdictionary.com/all-the-better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take out the "all the" and the sentence means the same thing:

> Sometimes relief makes triumph sweeter.

The "all the" is added for emphasis. You could use an "even" as a synonym:

> Sometimes relief makes triumph even sweeter.

The overall meaning (in this context) is that triumph is more enjoyable when a sense of relief comes with it. If this were used in a sports context, it might mean that winning a game is even sweeter when you've won the *deciding* game (as opposed to Game 1 of a 7-game series, for example).